# how to compare substrings in rows in different tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Starting to learn SQLite and still struggling with the fact that there are no loops. I have looked for an answer to my question now for one day and could not find it.

I have 2 tables: Table1 and Table2.
Table1 has a column which contains sentences, e.g. "I like apples".
Table2 has several columns: one of which would be Fruits (or Veggy ...), which contains "apple" and "banana".

I need to add a column to Table1 which sorts the foods into categories.

When using following tables:

```
Table1:

Sentence
----------------
I like apples.
I hate bananas.
I love cucumber.

Table2:

fruits       veggies
------       --------
apple        cucumber
banana       tomato
grape
```

The resulting table1 should look like the following.

```
Table1:

Sentence              category
----------------      --------
I like apples.        fruits
I hate bananas.       fruits
I love cucumber.      veggies
```

Comment: i have to say this is a horrible table design for table2 especially.

Comment: Your `Table2` does not appear to be relational.  I think each column should be in a separate table.

Comment: Or one table with an indicator to say whether each entry represents a fruit or a vegetable.

Comment: I am just in the beginning of learning SQL. I have many big tables (table1) containing many columns and rows full with data. One of the rows contains long strings. I wanted to categories the data regarding this long string, despite the fact that almost all the strings are different. Hence I created a new, quite small, table (table2) with categories by hand. The way I see it, table2 is not relational, but I don't see a need for it. If you know a better way to set up my system, then please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a better design to have two columns `category` and `name` in `Table2`.

Anyway, to add a column, use [ALTER TABLE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html):

```
ALTER TABLE Table1 ADD COLUMN category;
```

To find out whether a specific sentence belongs to a specific category entry, use [LIKE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
... WHERE Sentence LIKE '%apple%' ...
```

To assign the category, you have to check all entries in the category with a [correlated subquery](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#cosub):

```
UPDATE Table1
SET category = 'fruit'
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Table2
              WHERE Table1.Sentence LIKE '%' || fruits || '%');
```

(Same for `veggies`.)

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I needed.